# Regex - Match n last numbers without the last one

Tags: regex

With regex - replace, I am trying to format a number like this:

The leading number should be separated by a +. Moreover, the last number should be separated by a + as well. The more tricky part is, that adjacent 1s to the + to the middle part should be removed, without touching the first and the last number, e.g.,

011023040 -> 0+02304+0

111023920443 -> 1+02392044+3

13242311 -> 1+32423+1

I almost achieved this with the following regex:

```
 '^([0-9]{1})([1]+)?([0-9*)(0-9]{1}$'
```

And replace this with

```
'\1+\3+\4'
```

However, I have a problem with the last example, as this returns:

```
 1+324231+1
```

However, the one before the second + should be removed.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Please specify language/technology you're using in tags

Comment: What if the number has only 1 or 2 digits? What if the middle part is all 1's?

Comment: You have a syntax error in your regex.

Comment: `{1}` is redundant. `[1]` is the same as `1`. `(1+)?` is better written as `1*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a non-greedy quantifier:

```
^([0-9])1*([0-9]*?)1*([0-9])$
                ^^
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/dHPHMH/1)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to group the numbers in the following way

```
^(\d)(1*)(\d+)(\d)$
```

by using multiline and global flags.

The replacement should look like `\1+\3+\4`

Comment: Yes, but if I input 13242311, the output is 1+324231+1, but it should be 1+32423+1.